# How to create a macro to detect the type and print a number automatically?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a macro:

```
#define assert_equal(x, y) do {\
    typeof(x) evalx = x;\
    typeof(y) evaly = y;\
    _assert(evalx == evaly, __LINE__, __FILE__,\
        EVAL_TYPE_FORMATER(evalx)" != "EVAL_TYPE_FORMATER(evaly), evalx, evaly\
    )\
} while (0)
```

It should test for the equality of x and y and in case for inequality print both values.
the `_assert()` function looks like this:

```
void _assert(bool condition, size_t line, const char* file, char* format, ...);
```

I need help to create the macro `EVAL_TYPE_FORMATER()`. My initial idea was to check with `#if` and `typeof()` what format string I have to use. But this doesn't work, because I can not use `#if` in a macro expansion.

Here is my initial idea:

```
#define EVAL_TYPE_FORMATER(exp)\
    #if typeof(exp) == char ||\
        typeof(exp) == short ||\
        typeof(exp) == int\
        "%d"\
    #elif typeof(exp) == long\
        "%ld"\
    ...
```

But as you can see, there is a lot wrong with is. What can I do to fix this?

EDIT:

The newer approach is to use `_Generic` (thanks to @Someprogrammerdude).

```
#define EVAL_TYPE_FORMATER(exp) (_Generic((exp), \
        char: "%d", \
        short: "%d", \
        int: "%d", \
        long: "%ld", \
        ...
    ))
```

But the result of `_Generic` can not be used to concatenate it with a constant. `EVAL_TYPE_FORMATER(evalx)" != "EVAL_TYPE_FORMATER(evaly)` failes to compile now. Is there a way to solve that?

EDIT 2:

Worked around by changing `_assert()` to take 3 `char*` arguments now and concatenate the format string at runtime.

Comment: Perhaps you might be interested in [generic selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic)?

Comment: Now I have a new problem, I can not concatenate the result string of a `_Generic` expression. `EVAL_TYPE_FORMATER(evalx)" != "EVAL_TYPE_FORMATER(evaly)` failes to compile.

Comment: Please focus on one question. The history of your endeavors is not really helpful. Try for [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current design:

> Worked around by changing _assert() to take 3 char* arguments now and concatenate the format string at runtime.

If you intend to use printf, this is exactly what you have to do.

---

> Is there a way to solve that?

Sure! Create all possible combinations of all types and evaulate them in one expression:

```
#define assert_equal(x, y) do {\
    typeof(x) evalx = x;\
    typeof(y) evaly = y;\
    _assert(evalx == evaly, __LINE__, __FILE__,\
        EVAL_TYPE_FORMATER(evalx, evaly), evalx, evaly\
    )\
} while (0)

#define EVAL_TYPE_FORMATER(a, b) \
   _Generic(+(a) \
   , int: _Generic(+(b) \
      , int: "%d != %d" \
      , long: "%d != %ld" \
      , double: "%d != %f" \
      ) \
   , long etc....
```

Note: with `+` operator you can apply integer promotions on your argument, not to handle `char` `short` some cases. And I like putting `,` in front to indent nicely.

PS. Aaand you might be also interested in my project [yio](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/yio/), with it you would be able to do just `_assert(evalx == evaly, __LINE__, __FILE__, evalx, " != ", evaly)`. But what it does, it does the same as "passing 3 arguments" - for each argument a special function is passed to print the type of the argument -> the `evalx, " != ", evaly` becomes six arguments.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I should not do hard code all possible combinations. Also your project looks interesting, but I think it is overkill for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the preprocessor semantics don't allow it to know about C types.  The preprocessor is just that, a macro processor, it has no idea of C language (just to recognize C language tokens), but to expand text files filled with macro definition and macro expansion.

When the types are analysed (in the compiler) the preprocessor has finished with that part of the compilation unit and then it cannot go back and expand a macro differently, based on information that is gathered/generated by the compiler.

Even if you consider all the possible types that the C language can support, the preprocessor has no idea of what a C type is.  And it runs first in the chain.